# How to add Pagination in Expandable list view with Sqlite & Asynctask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

There is a Sqlite database, and I am experiencing problems with paging implementation inside of Expandable list view.

I want to fetch data (ten records at a time) and display these records in Explandable list view.

How can I achieve this goal via AsyncTask, doing background interaction with the server to display the information from the database?

**Main Activity**

```
/** The count. */
static int count=0;

listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
childDataHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<ChildInfo>>();
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
// readFromFile();
csvToSqlite();

// get the listview
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
txtViewLoadMore=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLoadMore);
// LoadMore button
        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
        btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");
        // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
        expListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore)
txtViewLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        count = count+1;
        //call AsyncTask for loading data in Expandable list view in background
        new NearBuyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();  
    }
});     
getExpandableListData();
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,childDataHashMap);
// setting list adapter
expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

}

```
public void getExpandableListData() {
    // Group data//
    // databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());{
    Cursor cursor;
    if(count==0)
    {
        cursor = databaseHelper.getGroupData();
    }
    else{
         cursor = databaseHelper.getLoadMoreData(count);
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.i(TAG, "cursor.getCount()" + cursor.getCount());
    do {
        String categoryDescription = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("categorydesc"));
        int categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("CategoryId"));

        // Child data//
        Cursor cursorChild = databaseHelper.getChildData(categoryId);
        List<ChildInfo> childList = new ArrayList<ChildInfo>();
        cursorChild.moveToFirst();
        while (cursorChild.moveToNext()) {
            String businessName = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild .getColumnIndex("BusinessName"));
            phoneNumber = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild.getColumnIndex("ph_Phone"));
            String landMark = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild .getColumnIndex("LandMark"));
            ChildInfo childInfo = new ChildInfo(businessName, phoneNumber,  landMark);
            childList.add(childInfo);
        }
        childDataHashMap.put(categoryDescription, childList);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```

**NearBuyAsyncTask**

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    activity = new MainActivity();
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
            mainActivity.getExpandableListData();
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

I am getting following error

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: I would go search for lazy loading scenarios and code samples in order to understand the logic of getting data before hand and cache it to use when needed. That is what you need to look for.